# Path range index config

Tags: marklogic

I've defined a path range index and also a path namespace, but the query gets a

> 'Prefix nv has no namespace binding'

If I add the namespace declaration in the query it works.  The query also has a default namespace defined (the same) and not sure if that may be causing the error.

namespace: `nv`   `http://developer.envisn.com/xmlns/envisn/netvisn/`

path:  `/nv:content/nv:crnData8/nv:defaultDescription/nv:value`

query:

```
declare default element namespace 
'http://developer.envisn.com/xmlns/envisn/netvisn/';
```

works when I add this to query:

```
declare namespace nv = "http://developer.envisn.com/xmlns/envisn/netvisn/";
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you defined your prefix in the admin interface? In left pane of the admin ui at port 8000, in the subtree for your database, is a node called "Path Namespaces". Click on it, go to the "Add" tab and you can map `nv` so your path reference will resolve.

## [Defining Namespace Prefixes Used in Path Range Indexes and Fields](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_47785)

When you define a path range index over XML documents and your path uses namespace prefixes, you must pre-define any namespace bindings used in the path expression. These namespace bindings can be used by multiple path range indexes.

To define a namespace binding, perform the following steps:

1. Click the Databases icon on the left tree menu.
2. Locate the database for which you want to create a namespace prefix binding, either in the tree menu or in the Database Summary table.
3. Click the name of the database for which you want to create a namespace binding.
4. Click the Path Namespaces icon in the tree menu, under the selected database.
5. Click the Add tab. The Path Namespaces Configuration page displays:
   [image]
6. In the Prefix field, enter the namespace prefix you intend to use for the element or attribute in the XPath expression in your path range index.
7. In the Namespace URI field, enter the namespace URI of the XML element or attribute in the XPath expression.
8. Click OK.